# Condition in generic lists

Tags: list, generics, c#-4.0

I'm wondering is there any condition instead of T-SQL like in generic lists in C# 4.0.

I've got a gridview on my page I got all datas and I need to search by name and lastname, so I think there must be but I couldn't find yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx), [`String.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) or [`String.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) as part of a predicate, either using [`List<T>.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) or [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) in LINQ.

For example:

```
var jons = people
    .Where(p => p.FirstName.StartsWith("Jon", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats called [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)